# integrating google places (autocomplete) within jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to integrate google's autocomplete places api (for location suggestions via http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places).  I would like the autocomplete to attach to a text input field that is located within a jquery "panel" (jqm version 1.4.2).  That panel is obviously hidden on page load and exposed when a button is clicked.

For the record, I've gotten autocomplete to work just fine when the input is not within the panel.  Therefore, I know I'm pulling in the js files fine and have a basic understanding of how things work.

I trigger the autocomplete binding with the following code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('locationSearch');

var options = {
//bounds: defaultBounds,
// types: ['establishment','(cities)']
};

// initiate autosuggest
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

When I view the page, the autocomplete functionality does not work.  I do not get any errors in firebug/etc.  However, if I manually run the commands in firebug console, the getelementbyid works, but it fails on the initialization with the following error message:

> TypeError: a[$G] is not a function
>
> D8()main.js... > eval (line 18) R8[I].Ml()main.js... > eval (line 34)
>   Kl/<()main.js... > eval (line 1) Q/<()main.js (line 15) ag()main.js
>   (line 27) Kl()main.js... > eval (line 1)
>
> ...Y("input"));var
>   c=a$G;null==c?this.L||a[W]("placeholder",this.H...
>
> http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/6/main.js line 375 >
>   eval line 375 > eval line 375 > eval line 375 > eval

I've even tried moving the initialization code into the "beforeopen" of the jqm panel, however, i get the same results.  My thoughts here were that the creation process of the panel temporarily removed the object from the DOM or something which would break the autocomplete binding, but that didn't help.

Any thoughts?  I'm clueless on where to go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: note that leaving the options blank is a valid approach and shouldn't be the cause of the error.  the problem is related to the location of the input (in the jqm panel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the answer.

continuing my investigation, i switched it to try to work in a jqm popup modal instead of the panel, and still no luck.  however, i changed my google terms to look for popup instead of panel and found this result:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/GZX0ynQNn1M

the solution in the response by G. Tandon (to his own question) worked fine for me.  turns out the results were being hidden behind the panel and popup modal and just needed to be brought to the forefront.

thanks!  (and a big shotout to g. tandon!)